# EE 2.8.1 - 3.5.7 upgrade successful but nor channel data visible in control panel

Tags: ee3, upgrade

We are in the process of upgrading several EE cms instances from v2.8.1 to v3.5.7 and have run into an issue. Each instance is running 2.8.1 with the MSM and 50 sites enabled (though in some cases not all used).

After successfully running the upgrade, we cannot view any of the existing channel entries through the Control Panel. We have confirmed that all entries are present in the exp_channel_titles and exp_channel_entries database tables. Also the Control Panel homepage boxes list correctly the Channels, Members and Content relevant to a given site. However, clicking Edit > View All or Edit > Channel results in an Entry Manager page with "No entries found"

If we publish an entry to any given channel it will save to both database tables as expected but is not viewable through the Control Panel.

Does anyone know why this might be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and I described it here: https://expressionengine.com/forums/topic/250487/no-entries-found-in-cp-after-updating

All entries disappear when I add a new entry. After 10-15 minutes they back again. The main difference is that I didn't update the CMS - it's just started one day.

As you can see, I couldn't find any solution for that yet. Have you?

---

**UPDATE:**

Finally I solved this problem!

I checked the logs of the database and… I found something like this:

> 2017-06-21T08:45:41.428236Z 17714007 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot add
>   field `wd_field_id_156_234` in table `tmp`.`#sql_1edc_0` because after
>   adding it, the row size is 8164 which is greater than maximum allowed
>   size (8126) for a record on index leaf page.

I solved it this way: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77398. So it was database issue.

I can’t see similar issue now. Entries are visible after updating/adding new entries and everything looks well.

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. But I think it is an issue with PHP7 as I successfully upgraded the CMS on another server running PHP5.6